# Generate textbox for row Index in list using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have to generate gridview in mvc 4 so i just bind the datas in list format and I need to edit the values in that list so i use one edit anchor control:

```
<a id="editable" href="#">Edit</a>
```

[image]

And i was took the row index value for this table,if i click this edit link that row index[0] will be change to textbox for that i had use contenteditable but i dont know how to change that normal text field to textbox using jquery with help of index value when i click the edit link